Flutter Dart - Foreach behaviour not clear here
Flutter version: 1.89+
I have a custom function as below:
  Future<List<CustomListItems>> getPrevChats() async {
    List<CustomListItems> vList = [];

    final Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> chatsRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("AT").snapshots();

    chatsRef.forEach((data) {
      for (var doc in data.docs) {
        vList.add(CustomListItems(doc.data()['message'], doc.data()['author']));
      }
      int i = vList.length;
      print("Inside loop count : $i");
    });
    int i = vList.length;
    print("Final : $i");
    return vList;
  }

To test values, I had embedded print list length temporarily. Now, when I call this function from main:
List<CustomListItems> vList1;

try {
  vList1 = await DBMethods().getPrevChats();
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
}

Output shows:
Final : 0
Inside loop count : 4
However, expecting value 4 for both outputs.

I think the problem is that fetching data is asynchronous. So the 'final' print is executed before the async operation ends.  If you await the sync operation then the final result will be correct.

First, let's simplify how the forEach behaves. Here is a simple example similar to your case:
List<String> getLetters() {
  List<String> letters = [];

  final dummyStrings = ["Foo", "Bar", "Hello", "World"];

  dummyStrings.forEach((element) {
    for (var letter in element.split("").toList()) {
      letters.add(letter);
    }
    int i = letters.length;
    print("inside: $i");
  });

  int i = letters.length;
  print("outside: $i");
  return letters;
}

The output is (as expected):

inside: 3
inside: 6
inside: 11
inside: 16
outside: 16

Which clarifies the behavior of the foreach. It invokes an action on each element of the iterable in iteration order.
However, the trick here is that in this example, we know that the code is getting executed synchronously, which is not the case in your code! Your output shows that "Final: 0" is getting printed even before  "Inside loop count: 4", which is not the expected result. It indicates that your code is running asynchronously.
Solution:
Although you declared the method getPrevChats() as async, it seems you forgot to add await when calling FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("AT").snapshots():
final chatsRef = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("AT").snapshots();

Update:
Thanks to @Ivo for mentioning that Stream has a different version of forEach method that returns Future<void>. Therefore, await can be executed with it, as:
final Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> chatsRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("AT").snapshots();

await chatsRef.forEach((data) { ...


I believe the issue actually is that there's a big difference between forEach on a List and forEach on a Stream. The forEach on a Stream returns a Future which could be awaited to, which means that OP could write await chatsRef.forEach((data) { to solve his issue I believe.
